# grep Between two words which is output of a curl command

Tags: regex

I am trying to get the "81" from the following curl output

"`{"testing":false,"locked":true,"number":81,"active":true,"service_id":"4bGnyAY1zFM8WBLc49LcbQ","staging":false,"created_at":"2018-11-13T04:18:49Z","deleted_at":null,"comment":"","updated_at":"2018-11-13T04:21:33Z","deployed":false}"`

I've tried  `sed -e 's/number\(.*\)active/\1/'` but it is rather suppressing those two words...

please help me out .. I am a fresher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is JSON output, do not try to parse it with regex. Instead, use the Python JSON library which comes standard with most systems that also have `grep`...

You would want a solution like the ones listed here:
https://www.cambus.net/parsing-json-from-command-line-using-python/

Example:

```
$ echo '{"testing":false,  "locked":true,"number":81,"active":true,"service_id":"4bGnyAY1zFM8WBLc49LcbQ","staging":false,"created_at":"2018-11-13T04:18:49Z","deleted_at":null,"comment":"","updated_at":"2018-11-13T04:21:33Z","deployed":false}' | python -c 'import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin))["number"]'
81
```

(replace 'echo' here with your `curl` command

Alternatively, if you could consider a program like `jq`, if it fits your use case: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: glad to hear it worked, consider Accepting it as an answer